# create 30 min interval for time series with different start time

Tags: r

I have data for electricity sensor reading with interval 15 min but the start time is not fixed for example
in this day it start at min 13 another day start from different minute
dateTime         KW
1/1/2013 1:13   34.70
1/1/2013 1:28   43.50
1/1/2013 1:43   50.50
1/1/2013 1:58   57.50
.
.
.//here start from min 02
1/30/2013 0:02  131736.30
1/30/2013 0:17  131744.30
1/30/2013 0:32  131751.10
1/30/2013 0:47  131759.00

I have data for one year and i need to have regular interval 30 min starting from mid night 00:00. 
I am new to R ..can anyone help me

Comment: If you have some code to show what you have attempted, it would help.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try:

```
dT <- as.POSIXct(strptime(df$dateTime, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M'))
grp <- as.POSIXct(cut(c(as.POSIXct(gsub(' +.*', '', min(dT))), dT,
       as.POSIXct(gsub(' +.*', '', max(dT)+24*3600))), breaks='30 min'))

df$grp <-  grp[-c(1,length(grp))]
df
#      dateTime       KW                 grp
#1  1/1/2013 1:13     34.7 2013-01-01 01:00:00
#2  1/1/2013 1:28     43.5 2013-01-01 01:00:00
#3  1/1/2013 1:43     50.5 2013-01-01 01:30:00
#4  1/1/2013 1:58     57.5 2013-01-01 01:30:00
#5 1/30/2013 0:02 131736.3 2013-01-30 00:00:00
#6 1/30/2013 0:17 131744.3 2013-01-30 00:00:00
#7 1/30/2013 0:32 131751.1 2013-01-30 00:30:00
#8 1/30/2013 0:47 131759.0 2013-01-30 00:30:00
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(dateTime = c("1/1/2013 1:13", "1/1/2013 1:28", 
"1/1/2013 1:43", "1/1/2013 1:58", "1/30/2013 0:02", "1/30/2013 0:17", 
"1/30/2013 0:32", "1/30/2013 0:47"), KW = c(34.7, 43.5, 50.5, 
57.5, 131736.3, 131744.3, 131751.1, 131759)), .Names = c("dateTime", 
"KW"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```